# How to pass custom CMake option to a KDE debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, kde-plasma-5, cmake

I want to enable CMake option `KIMAGEFORMATS_HEIF` (from [this MR](https://invent.kde.org/frameworks/kimageformats/-/merge_requests/16/diffs)) in the ubuntu 22.04 package `kimageformat-plugins`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I was able to piece together from these questions [1](https://superuser.com/questions/250437/how-to-pass-custom-options-to-configure-when-building-a-package-with-debuild) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787371/how-do-i-specify-build-options-for-cmake-based-projects) and [man dh-auto-configure](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dh_auto_configure.1.html):

```sh
mkdir temp_build_dir
cd !$
apt-get source kimageformats
cd kimageformats-*

sudo apt install libheif-dev  # or add libheif-dev to debian/control Build-Depends
sudo apt build-dep kimageformats

echo -e '
override_dh_auto_configure:
\tdh_auto_configure --buildsystem=kf5 -O--buildsystem=kf5 -- -DKIMAGEFORMATS_HEIF=ON
' >> debian/rules

sudo debuild -b -uc -us

sudo dpkg -i ../kimageformat-plugins_*_amd64.deb
```

- we download the source which is a package with a different name `kimageformats`.
- our option needs an additional dependency `libheif-dev`
- edit the `rules` files to override the configuration step. I copied the options `--buildsystem=kf5 -O--buildsystem=kf5` from a first run of `debuild`, and added my custom CMake option after `--` which allows pass-through.

Comment: Attention if you copy the commands from above: The line beneath 'override_dh_auto_configure:' must start with a TAB character. If you just copy the code from here you will get spaces and the following debuild command will fail with a "missing separator" error.

Comment: As of the 2022-04-28 question edit, the TAB character will be correct if you just copy and paste.